# React Button Filter disables Input Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm going to preface this with I am a complete noob with React, only been playing with it for a week and I'm ok with Javascript, so you will likely see terrible code.

I'm having an issue with some filtering functionality.  I have an input where I can filter out titles and that works just fine.  I also have button filtering which also works except for when I am selecting all.  When I select the All button the button filtering still works but the the input filtering no longer works.

What am I doing wrong?  I am guessing the biggest issue is in my `_hasData` function where I am doing an if condition.

If you don't want to check the API the `event_type` will return either `performance`, `package` or `flex package`.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

ButtonFilter.js

```
var ButtonFilter = React.createClass({
  handleFilterChange: function(index) {
    var value = $(this.getDOMNode()).children('div:nth-child(' + index + ')').children().attr('data-type');
    this.props.updateFilter(value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="button-group button-group--horizontal">
        <div className="button-group__item">
          <button className="button list button--active" data-type="all" ref="filterButton" onClick={this.handleFilterChange.bind(this, 1)}>All</button>
        </div>
        <div className="button-group__item">
          <button className="button calendar-view" data-type="performance" ref="filterButton" onClick={this.handleFilterChange.bind(this, 2)}>Performances</button>
        </div>
        <div className="button-group__item">
          <button className="button calendar-view" data-type="package" ref="filterButton" onClick={this.handleFilterChange.bind(this, 3)}>Packages</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   )
  }
});
```

SearchFilter.js

```
var SearchFilter = React.createClass({
  handleFilterChange: function() {
    var value = React.findDOMNode(this).value;
    this.props.updateFilter(value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input type="text" ref="filterInput" onChange={this.handleFilterChange} placeholder="Start typing..." />;
  }
});
```

Events.js

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var content;
    if (this.props.items.length > 0) {
      var items = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
        return (
          <div className="list-item" key={item.event_id}>
            <div className="list-info">
              <div className="list-info__venue">
                <h5 className="event-title">
                  <a href="#">{item.event_name}
                    <If condition={item.event_type != 'Performance'}>
                      <span className="event-type__badge">{item.event_type}</span>
                    </If>
                  </a>
                </h5>
                <span className="event-details">{item.event_date} | {item.event_venue}</span>
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         )
       });

       content = {items}
     } else {
       content = <p>No items matching this filter</p>;
     }

     return (
       <div>
          {content}
       </div>
    );
  }
});

var ListContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: [],
       nameFilter: '',
       typeFilter: ''
     };
  },

  componentWillMount: function () {
    this.loadEvents('http://private-4dfdc-ember26.apiary-mock.com/questions');
  },

  loadEvents: function(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
        data: data
      });
     }.bind(this),
     error: function(xhr, status, err, data) {
       console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
     }.bind(this)
   });
  },

  inputFilterUpdate: function(filterValue) {
    this.setState({
      nameFilter: filterValue
    });
  },

  buttonFilterUpdate: function(typeValue) {
    this.setState({
      typeFilter: typeValue
    });
  },

  _hasData: function() {
    var displayedItems = this.state.data.filter(function(item) {
      var match = item.event_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.nameFilter.toLowerCase()) || item.event_type.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.typeFilter.toLowerCase());

      if ( this.state.typeFilter.toLowerCase() == 'all' ) {
        return true;
      }

      return (match !== -1);
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sub__nav">
          <div className="search">
            <i className="fa fa-times"></i>
            <SearchFilter updateFilter={this.inputFilterUpdate} />
          </div>
          <ButtonFilter updateFilter={this.buttonFilterUpdate} />
        </div>
        <div className="list-view">
          <h6 className="list-view__title">Upcoming</h6>
          <List items={displayedItems} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return (
        <div>
          {this._hasData()}
        </div>
      )          
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return false
  }
});
```

Comment: From what I see, once event type filter is set (to 'all' or anything else), event name filter is not relevant anymore. Is that what you want? Or you want to have both filters satisfied?

Comment: I would like to have both filters satisfied so when I switch to all I am wanting all events to show up no matter what the type is and I am still able to filter through the input if need be.  Also if I select a button filter and start typing it filters only through the ones displayed which currently it doesn't do.  For instance when I select a button filter and then start typing it resets and shows everything that matches the input value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To satisfy both filters and bypass type filter if set to 'all', you can do this:

```
var displayedItems = this.state.data.filter(function(item) {
  var eventName = item.event_name.toLowerCase(),
      eventNameFilter = this.state.nameFilter.toLowerCase(),
      eventType = item.event_type.toLowerCase(),
      eventTypeFilter = this.state.typeFilter.toLowerCase();

  return eventName.indexOf(eventNameFilter ) > -1 &&
         (eventTypeFilter === 'all' || eventType.indexOf(eventTypeFilter ) > -1;
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: That breaks the filtering all together.

Comment: Modified the answer to show the whole function. How was it broken?

Comment: Nevermind, I misspoke.  I forgot to remove something :p.  thank you so much for your help!